# How to handle async call to mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm pretty new to nodejs which is probably why I'm asking this question. I recently discovered that calls being made with nodejs to any database are async.

As a former C# .Net programmer this is little bit a surprise for me. I'm just used to code synchronous  and it's ok to wait a little.

Currently I want to make a database call and with the returned result the code should continue to run. How to do this best? I found something about promises but I can't find the proper solution yet.

What I really want is something like this:

```
var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){

  console.log('Trading bot (re)started..');
  var wlist = [];

  wlist = db_connection.getWatchList_DB() ==> Database call here 


    if(wlist.length > 0){
      // Perform the rest of the code

    }

}, 5000);//300000 five minutes
```

So, for me it's ok to wait for the database call and continue with the fetched results. Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: Broadly, look for a database package that uses promises instead of callbacks. Once you have that, look into async/await features.

Comment: Like every other async call     conn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {//makesomthing }}) When you add more if these conn.querys you will see that they worl sysnchonous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) module which has inbuilt support for the promises.Code snippet from the official documentation

```
async function main() {
  // get the client
  const mysql = require('mysql2');
  // create the pool
  const pool = mysql.createPool({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});
  // now get a Promise wrapped instance of that pool
  const promisePool = pool.promise();
  // query database using promises
  const [rows,fields] = await promisePool.query("SELECT 1"); 
}
```

Also if you are very new to Node and async programming I would suggest you to learn about `Callbacks`,`Promises` and ofcourse `Async-Await`